# how to set fixed width for <td> in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use table element to align text to print to A4 page using the plain HTML i got perfect alignment which prints perfectly in a paper but when printing another name td is resized and i lose paper alignment as i have tapleted paper with fields like name already printed so i need right aligment so it would print in the same section on the paper.
any solution for this?

```
<table width = 100% border =1>      
<tr>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td> 
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td> 
            <td align = "right"><my><?php echo $name;?></my></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            <td align = "center"><my><?php echo $rollno;?></my></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>         
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
</tr></table>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set `table-layout: fixed` property for `table` element and `width: ?` (where `?` stands for the `width` value you want to provide) for your `td` element.

By the way, html attribute value should be always enclosed with quotes, *for example*: `border="1"`.

Comment: Thank you so much i am googling since 6 hours and even i found a post on stackoverflow which describes about same issue and a user was saying that defining tdf width  didn't worked so i didn't tried it 
bt in my case it worked thank you so much bro

Comment: [Unquoted attribute values](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#unquoted) are valid. But the [`width`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#attr-table-width) and [`align`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#attr-tdth-align) attributes are non-conforming obsolete features, so must not be used. The [`border`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#attr-table-border) attribute is valid but not recommended, CSS should be used instead.

Comment: What does `width: ?` mean? That is not valid CSS.